# Kitura with CouchDB - Problems Importing CouchDB Module

Tags: ios, swift, kitura, server-side-swift

I am trying to use CouchDB in my Kitura server side Swift app. I have my Package.swift with all the dependencies as shown below:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "hello-kitura",
    dependencies:[
        .Package(url:"https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git",majorVersion:1),
        .Package(url:"https://github.com/IBM-Swift/HeliumLogger.git",majorVersion:1),
        .Package(url:"https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine.git",majorVersion:1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-Kuery-PostgreSQL",majorVersion:0),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-CouchDB.git",majorVersion:1)
    ]
)
```

From the command line I ran the following to download the dependencies:

```
swift build
```

In my main.swift I have the following code:

```
import CouchDB   <-- No such module CouchDB
```

As you can see I get "No such module CouchDB". Any ideas!

UPDATE:

OS Version: OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Apple Swift Package Manager - Swift 3.0.2 (swiftpm-11750)

Comment: That's very strange. We have this example if it's helpful. https://github.com/IBM-Swift/TodoList-CouchDB/ but it's doing exactly what you described above.

Comment: Could you please provide some details: 1) The OS version you run swift build 2) swift and swift build versions: `swift --version` and `swift build --version`

Comment: @VadimEisenberg I just updated the original question with additional details.

Comment: UPDATE: I created a brand new project and it worked out fine without any issues. No idea what went wrong with the previous project.

Comment: Can you try this repo https://github.com/vadimeisenbergibm/hello-kitura ? It contains the same `Package.swift` and a simple `main.swift`. I have the same OS, swift and swift build as you and that example works for me.

Comment: Yeah! I created the new proj and it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Xcode Project Navigator you'll probably see that Kitura-CouchDB is missing from Dependencies (likely because you added it after you started the project).  One way to restore it (after you commit or backup first) is to rerun:

> swift package generate-xcodeproj